# Performing Dedekind cuts on hyperreals

Tags: real-analysis

It is a well-known fact that [the real numbers are the only complete totally ordered field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach).
So, if we perform the [Dedekind cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) construction on the [hyperreals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number), then the result must either be:

- The real numbers, or
- Something that isn't a complete totally ordered field.

I tried doing this construction to see what goes wrong, and I couldn't seem to prove that additive inverses exist (without using the [Archimedean principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property), which of course doesn't hold for the hyperreals).
But perhaps I'm just not clever enough.
So, my question is: is this the axiom that fails, or is it another one, or do we get a complete ordered field, ie. the real numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use only *internal* Dedekind cuts, then you get a field -- in fact, you just get the hyperreals themselves, as the hyperreals are already *internally* Dedekind complete.

But if you allow external Dedekind cuts, then you do get problems as you observed. One cut that, IMO, makes things easy to see is the cut:

- L = all negative numbers and finite numbers
- R = all positive transfinite numbers

The (external) Dedekind completion of the hyperreals has just the one element filling this gap between the positive finite and transfinite numbers. However, to be a field, if there are *any* numbers in this gap, we clearly need *many* numbers -- e.g. adding one to any number in this gap should give yet another number in this gap.

This is similar to your observation that additive inverses don't seem to exist; if they did, then we could use the above observation to show, e.g., that 1=0 fairly easily.

Comment: Thank you - this example does clarify things a lot for me.  Could you explain what you mean by internal Dedekind cuts and internally Dedekind complete?

Comment: @Aaron: The intuitive explanation is that anything that anything invoking standard analysis is external. The external Archimedean principle compares numbers with the standard integers -- there are hyperreal numbers larger than every standard integer, and thus the hyperreals are externally non-Archimedean. The *internal* Archimedean principle instead compares with the *nonstandard* integers -- for every hyperreal $x$, there is a hyperinteger larger than $x$, and so the hyperreals satisfy the internal Archimedean principle.

Comment: The simplest technical explanation, IMO, is simply to take "internal" as a primitive notion and understand it via the transfer principle. There is a standard power set operation $\mathcal{P}$, and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all subsets of the real numbers. By transfer, there is a non-standard power set operation ${}^\star \mathcal{P}$, and the internal subsets of ${}^\star \mathbb{R}$ are precisely the elements of ${}^\star \mathcal{P}({}^\star \mathbb{R)}$. There are other explanations, but this (and others like it) are the only ones that are really meaningful to me.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand. What you mean is that, while the reals satisfy "every bounded set has a least upper bound", the hyperreals also satisfy this, except with "internal set" in place of "set"?

Comment: @Aaron: That's right.